# regarding jquery effect

Tags: jquery

for jquery transfer effect we always mention from element and to element but if i need to show a div just center in page with transfer effect what i need to do. is there any good jquery plug in by which i can position html object like div, span,button etc anywhere in the page with transfer effect and also where i don't have to mention "to element like transfer effect" with minimum coding. please guide me.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to give that element a class and use this syntax:

```
selector.effect( "transfer", {arguments}, speed );
```

[Here is an example.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/effect-transfer.htm)

Comment: i asked for transfer like effect but where i will not specify to element. but in jquery trasnfer effect we have to mention from element and to element. but i want something like jquery plug in which generate transfer effect but where we dont have to mention to element. please guide me if u have any idea. thanks